# Check Multiple Variables Against Same Condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

When working with if statements in JavaScript, I've had to write out some rather lengthy conditionals. Here is an example one where three numbers have to be 0-100:

```
if ((num1 > 100 || num1 < 0) || (num2 > 100 || num2 < 0) || 
    (num3 > 100 || num3 < 0)) {
    return 'One of these is invalid';
} else {
    return 'Ok, we are good.';
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to shorten this up, I tried searching for similar questions, but couldn't find anything. But is it possible to do something like this in JavaScript? (or if not in JavaScript, is it possible to do it in other languages?)

```
if (num1, num2, num3 > 100 || num1, num2, num3 < 0) {
    return 'One of these is invalid';
} else {
    return 'Ok, we are good.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might create an array from the `num`s, then check whether `every` item in the array passes the test:

```
return [num1, num2, num3].every(num => num <= 100 && num >= 0)
? 'Ok, we are good.';
: 'One of these is invalid'
```

```js
const verify = (num1, num2, num3) => (
  [num1, num2, num3].every(num => num <= 100 && num >= 0)
    ? 'Ok, we are good.'
    : 'One of these is invalid'
);
console.log(verify(50, 50, 50));
console.log(verify(50, 100, 50));
console.log(verify(50, 101, 50));
```

If, by chance, the `nums` are arguments passed to the function, as in the above example, you can create an array from the arguments immediately using *rest* syntax:

```js
const verify = (someOtherArg, ...arr) => (
  arr.every(num => num <= 100 && num >= 0)
    ? 'Ok, we are good.'
    : 'One of these is invalid'
);
console.log(verify('someArg', 50, 50, 50));
console.log(verify('someArg', 50, 100, 50));
console.log(verify('someArg', 50, 101, 50));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with multiple values as individual variables you can put them in an array. In the case of validating/clamping values, you can actually get further using `Math.min` and `Math.max`:

```
if (Math.min(num1, num2, num3) < 0 || Math.max(num1, num2, num3) > 100) {
  return "No bueno, dude!"
} else {
  return "I dig it."
}
```